Conducting PCA on features of dataset
To preface, I am very new to quantitative finance and nowhere near the point of actually trading so forgive me if this question is trivial to most of you.
I am making a basic k-means clustering algorithm to identify was conducting PCA on my features to reduce dimensionality for better cluster analysis. I only identified 5 features as the rest of them I eliminated due to non-stationary and correlation.
If I'm not mistaken, the results I am getting state that the 14 day volatility accounts for pretty much all the explained variance within the dataset.
In the image, I have the dataset that I use and the results of the PCA algorithm.
Also, just to clarify, to my understanding the pca.components_ yields the eigenvector which you can then multiply by the dataset X_adj to attain the new dataset with the reduced dimension. Is this correct? Or am I supposed to simply extract the feature that the PCA indicates accounts for the most variance within the data?

Thanks!

You are not performing scaled PCA. Volume is 10e7 times bigger than any other column. It will dominate in variance terms. Try scaling columns to approximately the same order.
